# Mechanize br.open hangs indefinetly

Tags: python, mechanize-python

Theres another question that looks the same as this one, but its not.

I have this code>

```
    while True:
        iterator = iterator+1
        try:
            response = br.open('/cgi-bin/bet.pl?*********')
            tried = 0
        except :
            tried += 1
            print "Request Timed Out occurred "+str(tried)+" times. Waiting a few moments before try again."
            time.sleep(4)
            continue
```

When I try to test it, closing the connection it hangs on the response line. Like forever.
When I restabilish the internet, it stills hangs. And when I press Ctrl-C twice it goes to the except block. But it hangs again, it keeps printing the error message on a infinite loop. I have to press Ctrl-C a third time to program stops.
What have I been doing wrong? I have tried several solutions, but nothing.

EDIT:

Is this helpfull?

```
    > File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 203, in open
    File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 230, in _mech_open
    File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mechanize/_opener.py", line 193, in open
    File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mechanize/_urllib2_fork.py", line 344, in _open
    File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mechanize/_urllib2_fork.py", line 332, in _call_chain
    File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mechanize/_urllib2_fork.py", line 1170, in https_open
    File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mechanize/_urllib2_fork.py", line 1115, in do_open
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 979, in request
self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1013, in _send_request
self.endheaders(body)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 975, in endheaders
self._send_output(message_body)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 835, in _send_output
self.send(msg)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 797, in send
self.connect()
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1182, in connect
self.sock = ssl.wrap_socket(sock, self.key_file, self.cert_file)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 487, in wrap_socket
ciphers=ciphers)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 243, in __init__
self.do_handshake()
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 405, in do_handshake
self._sslobj.do_handshake()
```

SOLUTION:
First you change the relative path to absolute path in br.open argument. then...
Its a problem with urllib. I chaged `import urllib` to `import urllib2` and voilá!!!
Now the code looks like this:
`try:
             response = br.open('http://*****/cgi-bin/bet.pl?')
         except urllib2.URLError as e:
            print "URLError................."
            time.sleep(4)
            continue`

Comment: Can you use this trick to get traceback dump where your application is hung and add it to the question: https://opensourcehacker.com/2015/04/16/inspecting-thread-dumps-of-hung-python-processes-and-test-runs/

Comment: You never break out of you while statement. It's not going to do anything else.

Comment: @msanti I have a break just below. But the problem is that the loop is inside the except block.  why??? IDK

Comment: perhaps its the continue statement at the end, you're telling the program to continue with the while loop from that point on, any code below that won't run, try a pass statement in place of the continue statement

Comment: @msanti Thank you. Actually the continue statement is correct. The problem was that since I got the first error, I will be always be getting subsequent errors.
The program was hanging because I couldnt be using relative paths as br.open arguments, so it crashed. I put the complete HTTP address and it worked.

Comment: @georgesilva ahh that makes sense, happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

As @msanti mentioned, the address I was using as br.open argument could be wrong. So I changed, instead of a relative path to cgi-bin/bet.pl I put the complete address and it worked.
The reason the open method was working before I got the first urlException is a mistery to me.

Just posting in case anyone is facing the same problem.

Comment: The problem is back. Apparentry is a https issue. When I change the address to www.python.org, it works. But when I use a https address it hangs on br.open line of the code. The stack trace shows  a error in `File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 405, in do_handshake
self._sslobj.do_handshake()`   but no exception is throwed. It just hangs

Comment: Its a problem with urllib. I chaged `import urllib` to `import urllib2` and voilá!!!
Now the code looks like this:
`        try:
             response = br.open('http://*****/cgi-bin/bet.pl?')
         except urllib2.URLError as e:
            print "URLError................."
            time.sleep(4)
            continue  `